# Appium not navigating to right URL

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, appium, appium-ios

So I have installed appium by following these instructions: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/mobile-setup.md

I also have a protractor test that is working perfectly. However my problem is when I launch the test, it initiates the iOS simulator and launches safari perfectly, but always goes to http://0.0.0.0:4723/welcome first. Once it goes to that, after another 30 sec, it goes to my test and executes fine. The problem more specifically is when it is going to http://0.0.0.0:4723/welcome, since I am behind a corporate proxy, the page navigates to a captcha page which I have to manually enter. If I don't, it wont initiate my test and gets stuck at http://0.0.0.0:4723/welcome. I don't even know where this url (http://0.0.0.0:4723/welcome) is coming from. I want to remove this first initial test. I think it is something defaulted in Appium. This is my console output:

```
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Received response from socket send: '["PID:29882",
{"1":{"WIRTitleKey":"Page verifica...'
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Page changed: {"1":{"WIRTitleKey":"Page 
verification","WIRTypeKey":"WIRTypeWeb","WIRURLKey":
"https://captcha.gecirtnotification.com/pitc/}}
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Received app, but expected url 
('http://0.0.0.0:4723/welcome') was not found. Trying again.
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Found app id key 'PID:29880' for bundle 
'com.apple.mobilesafari'
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Found separate bundleId 
'com.apple.WebKit.WebContent' acting as proxy for 'com.apple.mobilesafari', 
with app id 'PID:29882'
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Trying out the possible app ids: PID:29882
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Selecting app PID:29882 (try #17 of 20)
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Sending '_rpc_forwardGetListing:' message to remote 
debugger
```

Comment: For iOS this is the default url you need to go to before you can execute a test. This is comming from Appium.

Comment: @wswebcreation There is no way to avoid this? This would be a disaster if I had to manually start the automation tests because of the captcha page I get.